# LINUX - shell script finding and listing all files with rights to write in directory tree

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Here is the code that i have soo far :

```
echo $(pwd > adress)
var=$(head -1 adress)
rm adress

found=0 #Flag 
fileshow()
{
    cd $1
    for i in *
        do
            if [ -d $i ] 
                then 
                    continue
            elif [ -w $i ]
                then 
                    echo $i 
                    found=1 
            fi
        done
    cd ..
}
fileshow $1

if [ $found -eq 0 ]
    then
        clear
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)There arent any executable files !!!$(tput sgr0)"
fi
```

Its working but it find files only in current directory.

I was told that i need to use some kind of recursive method to loop through all sub-directories but i dont know how to do it.

So if any one can help me i will be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of your script is to find the files below the current working directory that are not directories and are writeable to the current user. This can be achieved with the command:

```
find ./ -type f -writable
```

The advantage of using `-type f` is that it also excludes symbolic links and other special kinds of file, if that's what you want. If you want all files that are not directories (as suggested by your script), then you can use:

```
find ./ ! -type d -writable
```

If you want to *sort* these files (added question, assuming lexicographic ascending order), you can use `sort`:

```
find ./ -type f -writable | sort
```

If you want to use these sorted filenames for something else, the canonical pattern would be (to handle filenames with embedded newlines and other seldom-used characters):

```
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    echo "File '$REPLY' is an ordinary file and is writable"
done < <(find ./ -type f -writable -print0 | sort -z)
```

If you're using a very old version of `find` that does not support the handy `-writable` predicate ([added to v.4.3 in 2005](http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.findutils.bugs/2005-11/msg00054.html)), then you only have file permissions to go on. You then have to be clear about what you mean by “writable” in the specific context (writable to whom?), and you can replace the `-writable` predicate with the `-perm` predicates described in @gregb's answer. If you decide that you mean “writable by anyone” you could use `-perm /u=w,g=w,o=w` or `-perm /222`, but there's actually no way of getting all the benefits of `-writable` just using permissions. Also note that the `+` form of permission tests to `-perm` is deprecated and should no longer be used; the `/` form should be used instead.

Comment: The `-writable` option doesn't seem to be available in my version of `find` (`GNU find version 4.2.27`).

Comment: Ah, I have 4.4.2. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: yes that's fine but when i find those files i need to pass them to C process that will have to sort them ASC. I'm sorry i did not say that from beginning. So how can i do this with shell script ? I need to use some kind of variable to store my files or ? IDK as i say i'm not really familiar with the concept off shell scripting :)

Comment: I believe you're looking for the pipe `|`. So you'd do a `find ... | /path/to/c_process`. This redirects the output of the `find` command to the input of the C process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find`:

`find /path/to/directory/ -type f -perm -o=w`

Where the `-o=w` implies that each file has the "other write-permission" set.

or,

`find /path/to/directory/ -type f -perm /u+w,g+w,o+w`

Where `/u+w,g+w,o+w` implies that each file either has user, group, or other write-permissions set.